# Make a long line of characters wrap in HTML

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Users can enter text in a particular form of mine and I want to display that text in a table format. But sometimes users enter really long lines without spaces. So the text forces the table to be too wide.

I can limit the `td` element to have a `max-width`, but then the text keeps flowing over other cells. I can then set `overflow: hidden` and the text just gets cut off:
[image]

But I need to be able to read it all. Is there a way to wrap a long line of text in a table even if the text doesn't have spaces?

Comment: You can use [`word-break: break-word;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break)

Comment: css text-wrap property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-wrap.asp

Comment: @Bnjmn - `text-wrap` has no browser support!

Comment: @Adrift - that works, same as Dave below who answered 1 min earlier

Comment: You need to decide how you will handle the text. It is highly language-dependent where lines can be wrapped and exactly how this should happen. (E.g., in English, we normally use hyphenation.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS file on the element that requires it:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Here it is in action:

[Working example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap)

Comment: @Dave what if i want to wrap on space and some other special character without breaking the word

Comment: that's great .worked for me.